# How to get the new hclust object after using cutree function in R

Tags: r, tree, aggregate, hclust

How do I get the new hclust object after using cutree function? I know the standard output from cutree is a numerical vector that tells you the clusters each leaf node belongs. However, how can we get the aggregated tree structure after cutting at a certain height or by a given number of clusters?

```
library(gplots)
library(dendextend)

data <- iris[,1:4]
distance <- dist(data, method = "euclidean", diag = FALSE, upper = FALSE)
hc <- hclust(distance, method = 'ward.D')
dnd <- as.dendrogram(hc)
plot(dnd) 
abline(h=hc$height[140],col="red")
```

I searched related topics, but unfortunately cant find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
library(dplyr)
numberGroup = 10
dataClust = cbind(data, clust = cutree(hc, numberGroup))
dataClust = dataClust %>%
  group_by(clust) %>%
  summarise_all(mean)
dataClust %>%
  dist %>%
  hclust("ward.D2") %>%
  plot
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is it possible to construct a new hclust object directly from the original hclust object instead of the original distance matrix since the distance matrix may not be handy?
 I notice you use "mean" in summarise_all() to get a new distance matrix from the grouped tree; if I use the complete linkage to construct the hclust, shall I use another criterion?
The shape of the final subtree has been shifted from the original position; for example, group 10 moved into the middle instead of the last. Is that possible to keep the same shape as the original tree?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `cut` to get the pieces of the dendrogram. Since you seem to be interested in the height `h=hc$height[140]`

```
CutDend = cut(dnd, h=hc$height[140])
plot(CutDend$upper)
```

[image: Top part of dendrogram]

BTW,  you can also get the 10 branches below the cut line using `CutDend$lower`

Some additional details are available via `help(cut.dendrogram)`

> cut.dendrogram() returns a list with components $upper and $lower, the
> first is a truncated version of the original tree, also of class
> dendrogram, the latter a list with the branches obtained from cutting
> the tree, each a dendrogram.

**Addition:**
This is to address the additional requirement in the comments that the result should be an hclust object. You can convert the cut dendrogram back to an hclust using:

```
hcUpper = as_hclust_fixed(CutDend$upper)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I need the hclust object after cutting the tree at a certain height. How can I get the new hclust object from the original hclust object?